# In Redshift, can I use pl/pgsql features such as loops and variables without having to create a stored proc?

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'd like to use pl/pgsql features such as loops, variables, execute dynamic sql, IF statements, etc without having to create a stored proc. Is there a way to run a block of adhoc pl/pgsql? I don't want to have to create any permanent objects on the database. Not sure if it's possible, but I'd also be okay with being able to create a stored proc that is only saved to the session.

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is 'no' but the real question is why do you want to do this?  When I see questions like this I ask if you know about window functions.  These are usually the answer to processes that people think need a looping code structure.

Comment: Redshift being based on PostgreSQL doesn't support `DO` statements that you could use as a anonymous code block.